# Contour integral representation for the reciprocal of the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading this link [https://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node14.html](https://www.nbi.dk/%7Epolesen/borel/node14.html) about the proof of the contour integral representation of the reciprocal of the Gamma function. I'm stuck and need help in only one part of the proof that is not entirely clear for me. How can I justify that

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\delta e^{i \theta})^{z-1}e^{\delta(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})}\delta e^{i \theta}i d \theta =0$$
in the proof given in the above link?

Thank you for the help and any hint or thoughts will be very helpful.

Comment: There is a factor of $\delta$ inside the integral, so doesn't this follow instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note  $|(\delta e^{i \theta})^{z-1}e^{\delta(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})}\delta e^{i \theta}| = e^{\delta\cos{\theta}}\delta^{\Re(z)}e^{-\theta \Im(z-1)} $, and then note this latter function is clearly integrable; indeed, the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is $\delta^{\Re(z)} \frac{2\sinh(\pi(\Im(z-1) - \delta))}{\Im(z-1) - \delta}$,

Since we clearly get limitwise convergence to zero (indeed, as $\delta^z$) we conclude the integrand vanishes by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.